# TypeError when applying a function to every element of a nested array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to vectorize the function apply to an array of arrays in order to avoid the loop.

The input array `arr` is

```py
array([array([], dtype=float64),
       array([0.03, 0.04,])],
      dtype=object)
```

If I do a loop

```py
for a in arr:
    np.exp(-a)
```

I don't get any error . Instead, with `np.apply_along_axis`

```py
np.apply_along_axis(func1d=lambda x: np.exp(-x), axis=0, arr=arr)
```

I get an error `TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type numpy.ndarray which has no callable exp method`. I believe there is some type mismatch but don't really understand why looping through the array works just fine. Also doing a simpler operation like `lambda x: x * 6371` produces the expected result.

It may also be that `np.apply_along_axis` is not the best approach here and I may need to convert `arr` to a structure that allow for vectorization.

Comment: `apply_along` doesn't 'vectorize' or improve speed, even when it works.  With object dtype, math operations are all done at list comprehension speeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [22]: arr = np.array([np.array([], dtype=np.float64),
    ...:        np.array([0.03, 0.04,])],
    ...:       dtype=object)
In [23]: arr
Out[23]: array([array([], dtype=float64), array([0.03, 0.04])], dtype=object)
```

Math on an object dtype array is hit or miss.  Basically it has to iterate on the objects, apply the "math operation" to each.  For basic operators this generally works:

```
In [24]: arr * 2
Out[24]: array([array([], dtype=float64), array([0.06, 0.08])], dtype=object)
```

But for functions like `exp` it tries to do `[i.exp() for in in arr]`, which produces the error.  Few object classes implement `exp` as a method.

```
In [25]: np.exp(arr)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'exp'
    
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type numpy.ndarray which has no callable exp method
```

You have to do the `exp` explicitly yourself:

```
In [26]: [np.exp(i) for i in arr]
Out[26]: [array([], dtype=float64), array([1.03045453, 1.04081077])]
```

`apply_along_axis` is never a performance tool, but it can simplify (the appearance of) nest loops for 3d+ arrays.  Your `arr` is 1d.

When `apply...` doesn't behave as you expect, use a function that displays its argument.  That will give you a better idea of what `apply...` is actually doing:

```
In [27]: def foo(i):
    ...:     print(i)
    ...:     return i*2
    ...:     

In [28]: np.apply_along_axis(foo, axis=0, arr=arr)
[array([], dtype=float64) array([0.03, 0.04])]
Out[28]: array([array([], dtype=float64), array([0.06, 0.08])], dtype=object)
```

`apply...` just passed `arr` whole to `foo`.  It did not "iterate".  `arr` is 1d, and you told it to pass 1d arrays to `foo`.

I can tweak the shape of `arr` to make it pass the individual subarrays to the function:

```
In [30]: np.apply_along_axis(foo, axis=1, arr=arr[:,None])
[array([], dtype=float64)]
[array([0.03, 0.04])]
Out[30]: 
array([[array([], dtype=float64)],
       [array([0.06, 0.08])]], dtype=object)
```

But there's no speed advantage to doing this.  Stick with your iteration.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying, I feared that. Any way of speeding up applying an operation row-wise on a list of arrays with different sizes or iteration really the only way?